# Different function invocations on list items based on index without when

Tags: collections, kotlin

I have a list of items

```
val itemList = mutableListOf<Item>()
```

and this list is populated by a separate code and its size is **unknown** but not more than **5**

And I have 5 different functions, which take **item** as parameter and perform operations on the Item based on index

```
fun operation1(item:Item)
fun operation2(item:Item)
fun operation3(item:Item)
fun operation4(item:Item)
fun operation5(item:Item)
```

Now, I want to iterate over itemList and perform different operations on every item based on its index, so as to avoid IndexOutOfBoundsException

I know it can done using **for combined with when**, but I want to know if it can be done without using **when** for **index**.
Like passing functions as varargs and code performs operations on each item intelligently

Or through use of any kotlin powers like extension functions or lambda functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with built in functions: you create a list of your functions with function references:

```
val operations = listOf(::operation1, ::operation2, ::operation3, ::operation4, ::operation5)
```

Then you pair up each of these with items with an operation. The `zip` method's result has the length of the shorter of the two collections, in case their size doesn't match. Then you just iterate on these, calling the operation that's paired with each item (using a destructuring declaration for the `forEach` function's lambda parameter).

```
itemList.zip(operations).forEach { (item, operation) ->
    operation(item)
}
```

---

Another solution with your own extension function:

```
fun <T> List<T>.performOperations(vararg operations: (T) -> Unit) {
    this.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
        operations[index](item)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
itemList.performOperations(::operation1, ::operation2, ::operation3, ::operation4, ::operation5)
```

Note that this currently doesn't handle size mismatches gracefully, it expects a function for every item. You can change it to this form so that it expects an item for every function instead:

```
fun <T> List<T>.performOperations(vararg operations: (T) -> Unit) {
    operations.forEachIndexed { index, operation ->
        operation(this.get(index))
    }
}
```

Comment: list of function references definitely looks like the way to go. Great solutions

Comment: the zip with foreach works flawlessly for size mismatches